# Is there a way to do a weighted ranking of 3 columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have three columns that I want to rank based on certain weights. Here is an example of the dataframe I am working with:

```
Sales Revenue             Product Count           Average Sales/Product
1005650                   30                      33521.67
100223                    5                       20044.60
72233                     2                       36116.50
1005657                   13                      77358.23
1002233                   25                      40089.32
```

I want to create a ranking that puts, for example, 45% of the weight on Average Sales/Product, 35% weight on Sales Revenue, and 20% weight on Product Count. I know that in pandas this can be done:

```
col1 = sales["Sales Revenue"].astype(str)
col2 = sales["Average Sales/Product"].astype(str) 
col3 = sales["Product Count"].astype(str)

sales['Rank'] = (col2+col1+col3).astype('int64').rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int64)
sales = sales.sort_values('Rank')
```

But I don't understand how this method works, because it does rank but the logic behind it I can't seem to understand. Is there a way I can create a ranking system that based on percentage weights would be able to create a ranking with increased emphasis on Average Sales/Product, then Sales Revenue, then Product Count.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compute the weighted average and rank it:

```
sales['Rank'] = (sales['Average Sales/Product'] * 45 +
        sales['Sales Revenue'] * 35 + sales['Product Count'] * 20).rank(
            ascending=False).astype('int64')
```